# Bind, Call и Apply в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, функции

Как это работает? Для полного понимаю, посмотрите [статью на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/199456/).

```js
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

slice([1,2,3], 0, 1); // => [1]

var bind = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind);
```

Comment: `Для полного понимаю, посмотрите статью на Хабре.` - нет, так не пойдет.  Всё относящееся к вопросу должно быть в нём. А читать статьи на хабре, чтобы ответить на вопрос - ну это как-то перебор

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все что нужно для вопроса я указал, просто там есть полная таблица того, как наводились примеры.

Comment: Честно говоря непонятно в чем вопрос заключается. Как работают Bind, Call и Apply? Тогда причем тут "Я пробовал аналогичную манипуляцию с функцией и контекст был window"? То есть непонятен у кого когда какой контекст? Или что? Вопрос надо бы пояснить.

Comment: _Я пробовал аналогичную манипуляцию_ - нет, ты сделал совсем другое. Обрати внимание что происходит с результатом функции `Function.prototype.call.bind` в первом сниппете, и в твоем примере

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);` возвращается функция `call` с привязным контекстом в виде метода `slice`. Вызывая переменную `slice`(функцию call) и передаем ей `массив [1,2,3]` и аргументы `0, 1` и это срабатывает, но я не пойму как это работает.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо что подметил.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, а ты читал статью на которую ты ссылаешься в вопросе? Там вроде подробно рассмотрено, что происходит в этой строчке кода

Comment: @Grundy я понял. просто в `this` метода `call` вшили метод `slice`. ты не знаешь почему ошибка?

`var a = Function.prototype.call;

a();
VM810:3 Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
    at <anonymous>:3:1`

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, EDGE дает более осмысленную ошибку: _Function.prototype.call: 'this' is not a Function object_